Maui application in ios simulator Visual Studio Mac 2022 does not take up the entire screen
I am migrating my application from Xamarin to Maui. When running on the iPhone 15 iOS 17.0 simulator, the content does not occupy the entire height of the phone, there is a space above and below.
I am using Visual Studio Mac 2022
.net 8.0
Xcode 15.2
I am working with prism.maui https://checox.com/finally-prism-maui-is-here-how-to-install-it/
Example

This my code xaml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Maui;assembly=FFImageLoading.Compat.Maui"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             xmlns:sofadconControles="clr-namespace:UI_MovilM.Controles.SofadconControles"
             xmlns:icons="clr-namespace:UI_MovilM.Helpers.Icons"
             x:Class="UI_MovilM.Views.General.Pantallas.FrmLoginPage"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:UI_MovilM.ViewModels.General.Pantallas"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
  <Grid>
    <ffimageloading:CachedImage
      Aspect="Fill"
      CacheDuration="30"
      CacheType="All"
      DownsampleToViewSize="True"
      ErrorPlaceholder="no_image.jpg"
      FadeAnimationEnabled="False"
      FadeAnimationForCachedImages="False"
      Source="fondomovil" />
    <Grid Padding="10" RowDefinitions="3*,42*,53*,2*">
      <!--#region Logo-->
      <Grid Grid.Row="1" RowDefinitions="*,Auto" Margin="25,0,25,0" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Image
          HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=220 , Tablet=470}"
          Aspect="AspectFit"
          Source="sofadconfacturero" />
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1"
                     Orientation="Horizontal"
                     Spacing="5"
                     HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                     Margin="{OnPlatform Android='0,3,0,0' , iOS='0,2,7,0'}"
                     TranslationY="{OnPlatform Android=-5 ,iOS=0}">
          <Label
            Text="Versión"
            TextColor="#2F5872"
            FontSize="{OnIdiom Phone=14, Tablet=18}"
            FontFamily="{StaticResource RobotoMedium}" />
          <Label
            Text="{Binding Version}"
            TextColor="#2F5872"
            FontSize="{OnIdiom Phone=14, Tablet=18}"
            FontFamily="{StaticResource RobotoMedium}" />
        </StackLayout>
      </Grid>
      <!--#endregion-->
      <!--#region Formulario-->
      <Grid
        Grid.Row="2"
        Margin="25,3,25,6"
        RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto,Auto, Auto">
        <!--#region Titulo-->
        <Label
          Grid.Row="0"
          Margin="0,2,0,0"
          Style="{StaticResource EstiloControlAcceso}"
          Text="Control de Acceso" />
        <!--#endregion-->
        <!--#region Entry Usuario-->
        <Frame
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="0,10,0,0"
          BackgroundColor="Transparent">
          <StackLayout Spacing="0">
            <sofadconControles:SacTextBox
              Text="{Binding Usuario}"
              SacValidacion="Numerico"
              MaxLength="10"
              Placeholder="Cédula de Identidad"
              SacSeleccionadoFocus="True"
              ColorText="Black" />
          </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <!--#endregion-->
        <!--#region Entry Contraseña-->
        <Frame
          Grid.Row="2"
          Margin="0,10,0,0"
          BackgroundColor="Transparent">
          <StackLayout Spacing="0">
            <sofadconControles:SacTextBox
              Text="{Binding Clave}"
              SacActivado="True"
              SacValidacion="AlfaNumerico"
              Placeholder="Contraseña"
              SacSeleccionadoFocus="True"
              IsPassword="True"
              ColorText="Black"
              ShowIcoPassword="True"
              CompletedCommand="{Binding LoginCommand}"
              LineColor="{StaticResource BlueBorderColor}" />
          </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <!--#endregion-->
        <!--Contenedor de Botones-->
        <FlexLayout Grid.Row="3" Direction="Column">
          <Frame
            Margin="0,5,0,0"
            Padding="8"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            BorderColor="{StaticResource BlueBorderColor}"
            HasShadow="False"
            CornerRadius="8">
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <Label
              FontFamily="{StaticResource RobotoMedium}"
              FontSize="{OnIdiom Tablet=25, Phone=20}"
              HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
              Text="ACCESO"
              TextColor="{StaticResource ColorLogin}"
              VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
          </Frame>
          <!--#endregion-->
          <!--#region Boton de Registrarse-->
          <Frame
            Margin="0,5,0,0"
            Padding="8"
            xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:FrmLoginPageViewModel}}, Path= BtnRegistrarseCommand}"
            xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True"
            xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimationColor="White"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            HasShadow="False"
            BorderColor="{StaticResource BlueBorderColor}"
            CornerRadius="8"
            IsVisible="{Binding IsRegistrarse}">
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BtnRegistrarseCommand}" />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <Label
              FontFamily="{StaticResource RobotoMedium}"
              FontSize="{OnIdiom Tablet=25, Phone=20}"
              HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
              Text="REGISTRARSE"
              TextColor="{StaticResource ColorLogin}"
              VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
          </Frame>
          <!--#endregion-->
          <!--#region Botones de Volver/ Recuperar y olvido Contraseña-->
          <Grid ColumnDefinitions="40*,60*">
            <!--#region Boton de Volver-->
            <Frame
              xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding NavigateBackCommand}"
              xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True"
              xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimationColor="White"
              Margin="0,8,0,0"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Padding="6"
              HasShadow="False"
              IsVisible="{Binding IsVolver}">
              <Frame.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0">
                  <GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="Transparent" />
                  <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
              </Frame.Background>
              <Label
                FontFamily="AwesomeFont-Solid"
                FontSize="{OnIdiom Tablet=45, Phone=30 }"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Text="{x:Static icons:FontAwesomeSolid.ArrowLeft}"
                TextColor="{StaticResource ColorLogin}" />
            </Frame>
            <!--#endregion-->
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
              <StackLayout>
                <!--#region Recuperar Usuario -->
                <Frame
                  xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding RecuperarUsuarioCommand}"
                  xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True"
                  CornerRadius="5"
                  WidthRequest="40"
                  IsVisible="False"
                  HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=30 , Tablet=50}"
                  FlexLayout.Order="0">
                  <Frame.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0">
                      <GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="Transparent" />
                      <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Frame.Background>
                  <Label
                    FontSize="{OnIdiom Tablet=16, Phone=13}"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Text="¿Recuperar Usuario?"
                    TextColor="#014164"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                </Frame>
                <!--#endregion-->
                <!--#region Olvido Contraseña -->
                <Frame
                  Margin="0,5,0,0"
                  CornerRadius="5"
                  HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=30 , Tablet=50}"
                  FlexLayout.Order="1">
                  <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding RecuperarUsuarioCommand}"/>
                  </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                  <Frame.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0">
                      <GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="Transparent" />
                      <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Frame.Background>
                  <Label
                    FontSize="{OnIdiom Tablet=18, Phone=13}"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Text="¿Olvidó su Contraseña?"
                    TextColor="#014164"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                </Frame>
                <!--#endregion-->
                <!--#region Necesitas Ayuda -->
                <Frame
                  Margin="0,2,0,0"
                  xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True"
                  CornerRadius="5"
                  HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=30 , Tablet=50}"
                  IsVisible="True"
                  FlexLayout.Order="2">
                  <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BtnAyudaCommand}"/>
                  </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                  <Frame.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0">
                      <GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="Transparent" />
                      <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Frame.Background>
                  <Label
                    FontSize="{OnIdiom Tablet=18, Phone=13}"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Text="¿Necesitas Ayuda?"
                    TextColor="#014164"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                </Frame>
                <!--#endregion-->
              </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <!--#endregion-->
        </FlexLayout>
      </Grid>
      <!--#endregion-->
    </Grid>
    <!--#region Imagen logo Sofadcon-->
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End">
      <Image
        Source="unproductosofadcon"
        HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Tablet=60 , Phone=40}"
        Margin="0,0,0,10" />
    </StackLayout>
    <!--#endregion-->
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>


This my file info.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/appicon.appiconset</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>


There appear to be some non English comments above each code block.  Please [edit] your question to be English only, as StackOverflow is an English only site

Try using the safe area. Also, how is the page hosted? Maybe its parent causes this?

I did add that safe area property but it didn't work.
xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
ios:Page.UseSafeArea="True"

What do you mean about how the page is hosted, sorry?
You are working with Prism, and from PrismStartup I command the page to load to be called.

internal static class PrismStartup
{
public static void Configure(PrismAppBuilder builder)
{
builder.RegisterTypes(RegisterTypes).CreateWindow("NavigationPage/FrmLoginPage");
}
private static void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Splash, SplashViewModels>();

    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<FrmLoginPage, FrmLoginPageViewModel>();

